# C++ Xcode won't run my for loop (very short)

Tags: c++, xcode

I want to continue reading Stroustrup PPUC++, but I'm stuck! I wrote a BleepOutTheBadWords program a few days ago and it worked. I tried to write the program with my younger brother a few days ago and I failed. This is essentially a program I wrote to figure out what is going wrong. It is not printing out each word in the "sentence" vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" // Stroustrup header file
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Write a sentence." << endl;

    vector<string> sentence;

    // Put user input into "sentence" vector
    for (string word; cin >> word; )
        sentence.push_back(word);

    // Print each word in "sentence" vector
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); ++i)
        cout << sentence[i] << endl;

    // Keep window open and return 0 to show program succeeded    
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

The answer is going to be obvious. Please just state the obvious if you are so kind. I looked through the suggested readings on two different pages before posting this.

Comment: What is "I failed"? Ask a specific question.

Comment: if it was obvious you didnt need to ask the question. Your question should contain the desired behaviour and actual behaviour. What is the meaning of "failed" ?

Answer (score 3):

> XCode won't run my for loop

Your loop is running. The thing that you missed is how to terminate the loop.

`for (string word; cin >> word; )`

This loop will terminate when `cin >> word` evaluates to false. Normally, i.e. without an error condition, it will evaluate to false when your input is finished. The exact process to signal an end of stream, or EOF, is platform dependent. If you are running this program on OSX then the most common way to signal EOF is to hit `Ctrl + D` button, unless you changed the default configuration of your keyboard. Once you signal EOF this input loop will terminate and you will be able to see the output.

I'm pretty much sure that Stroustrup discussed this on his book (though I can not refer to an exact page number). However "Chapter 10: Input and Output Streams" of his books covers these things in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wish cin>>word auto-evaluated to false when my input is finished, cause I didn't have to signal an EOF just a few days ago.

Comment: How can it auto-evaluated to false? How can it know when your input is finished? It can't read your mind. Few days ago you probably used  `getline` which ends at the end of line, i.e. after pressing enter. But `cin >> word` doesn't end with new line. So you have to inform it that you are done with input.